# What does the Planetary Union logo depict?

Tags: the-orville

The Planetary Union logo features prominently in The Orville, on uniforms, walls and on the Union's ships.

To my mind it kinda looks like a set of tentacles high-fiving each other, but do we know (from an interview, perhaps) what the Union logo actually represents?

[image]

Comment: Given the level of humor on the show I wouldn't be surprised if it was phallic in nature.

Comment: Needs a Word Of God answer, but given the similarities with star trek the show has I would assume its a starmap depicting the home stars of the 4 founding members of the Union.  If it actually has a meaning at all and isnt just a random prop someone came up with.

Comment: @PeterM, I think you should get that checked out.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to represent the different species coming together to explore the galaxy. The six trails (representing different species) come together in the classical rocket fuselage. The six trails also suggest thrust to propel the rocket into/past the star field. That's just my own head cannon though without a shred of official justification so I won't post that as an answer.

Comment: [Was The Orville Planetary Union Logo inspired by Star Trek TNG Encounter at Farpoint Aliens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yQKT5Qv2Bs)? - An interesting possibility.